# Can't get index.php removed from kohana URL in IIS 7

Tags: php, iis, kohana, url-rewrite-module

I know there are already several other posts for this topic, but I've tried everything they've said and I can't seem to get it to work.

I have the php kohana framework installed in http://localhost/kohana and it's working. The problem is that I can't get the /index.php/ removed from my URL.

I have tried importing the .htaccess file form the install into IIS URL Rewrite module, but no luck.

My bootstrap is the following

```
Kohana::init(array(
'base_url'   => '/kohana',
'index_file' => ''
));
```

My web.config that I have put in my /kohana direcotry looks like so

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(?:application|modules|system)\b.*" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 2">
                <match url=".*" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

I have also tried the rewrite rules on [this page](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/5000/iis-77-5-url-rewrite-and-kohana/p1)

Nothing seems to work. If I go to http://localhost/kohana/index.php/welcome it works. If I go to http://localhost/kohana/welcome I get a 404 error from IIS (not a 404 in kohana).

I feel like I'm beating my head against the wall, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just gave up and went with Apache on my Windows server. Removing the index.php worked like a charm on the first try.

Answer (score 1):

Your web.config file is ok, I'm using the same and never had any problems.
I think the problem may be in your bootstrap.php. Try this:

```
Kohana::init(array(
   'base_url'   => '/kohana/',
   'index_file' => FALSE
));
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and I downloaded this file http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Then I re-openned the IIS and see that there was a new option "URL Rewrite". In the right bar of URL Rewrite have a link labeled "Import Rules...", so I imported the ".htaccess" and removed the line "RewriteBase /" because it raised an error. Then, problem solved!

### Step-by-step:

- Download/Install http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite
- Goto IIS Manager: sites/[YOUR_DOMAIN]
- Open the new module "URL Rewrite"
- Open the right link "Import Rules..."
- Import your ".htaccess" file and remove the line "RewriteBase /"
- Save!

Well, I hope this help somebody because I didn't find any step-by-step like this to solve my problem.

Sorry for my english.